# Writing a string with tags in an XML file turns into giberrish

Tags: php, xml, encoding, simplexml

I tried writing into my XML file with simpleXML and I wanted to write a string with the value `"<test>asd</test>"` then it turned into total giberrish (I know this is related with encoding formats but I don't know the solution to fix this, I tried turning into `encoding="UTF-8"` but it still yield a similar result)

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<userinfos>
<userinfo>
    <account>
        <user>TIGERBOY-PC</user>
        <toDump>2014-02-04 22:17:22</toDump>
        <nextToDump>2014-02-05 00:17:22</nextToDump>
        <lastChecked>2014-02-04 16:17:22</lastChecked>
        <isActive>0</isActive>
        <upTime>2014-02-04 16:17:22</upTime>
        <toDumpDone>1</toDumpDone>
        <systemInfo>&lt;test&gt;asd&lt;/test&gt;</systemInfo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <user>TIGERBOY-PCV</user>
        <toDump>2014-02-04 22:17:22</toDump>
        <nextToDump>2014-02-05 00:17:22</nextToDump>
        <lastChecked>2014-02-04 16:17:22</lastChecked>
        <isActive>1</isActive>
        <upTime>2014-02-04 16:17:22</upTime>
        <toDumpDone>1</toDumpDone>
    </account>
</userinfo>
</userinfos>
```

My PHP File:

```
    <?php

    //Start of Functions
    function changeAgentInfo()
    {

        $userorig = $_POST['user'];

        $userinfos = simplexml_load_file('userInfo.xml'); // Opens the user XML file
        $flag = false;

        foreach ($userinfos->userinfo->account as $account) 
        {       

            // Checks if the user in this iteration of the loop is the same as $userorig (the user i want to find)
            if($account->user == $userorig)
            {
                $flag = true; // Flag that user is found

                $meow = "<test>asd</test>";
                $account->addChild('systemInfo',$meow);
            }
        }

        $userinfos->saveXML('userInfo.xml');

        echo "Success";
    }
    //End of Functions

    // Start of Program
    changeAgentInfo();


?>
```

Thank you and have a nice day =)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions, instead edit the previous one: [Error in adding a string of elements into an iterated XML file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22112453/367456) - As this one has been answered already, please delete the previous one if it is not needed any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't gibberish; it is simply the [XML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for `<` (`&lt;`) and `>` (`&gt;`).  To add nested XML elements with SimpleXML, you can do the following:

```
$node = $account->addChild('systemInfo');
$node->addChild('test', 'asd');
```

You'll see that first we [add a node](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) to `<account>`, then add a child to that newly created node.

If you plan on adding several children to the `<systemInfo>` element, you could perhaps do the following:

```
$items = array(
    'os' => 'Windows 7',
    'ram' => '8GB',
    'browser' => 'Google Chrome'
);
$node = $account->addChild('systemInfo');
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $node->addChild($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I planed on having a string with multiple nested elements with this code, so is there any quick way to do it instead of (parsing the string and do a heavy read and write to the said string then create multiple children for it)?
Also thank you for the response =)
thank you for the response =)

Comment: @SaggerAl-Saadi:  See my edited answer for a possible solution.

Comment: thanks man =)
This gave me a new idea to implement it though I implemented it differently where I just made two XML loads, one for string and one for the file, =)

Answer (score 0):

The [addChild function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) is used to add the child element to an Xml node. You are trying to add xml instead of text.

You have

```
$meow = "<test>asd</test>";
$account->addChild('systemInfo',$meow);
```

You should change it to

```
$account->addChild('systemInfo','my system info text');
```